# How to customize CalendarView without any external libraries in Android (Java)?

Tags: java, android

I would like to customize the default Android CalendarView look (things like using any other shape instead of a circle, navigation between years instead of months etc.)

I have seen other answers but most of them use external libraries. Is it possible without libraries?

Comment: @mordor619 Thank you for your response, but is it possible to do this without using any libraries?

Comment: you can change bgcolor and stuff but you wont be able to design a custom calendar without external libraries

Comment: Try looking at [Create your own custom calendar view](https://medium.com/meetu-engineering/create-your-custom-calendar-view-10ff41f39bfe).